# ruby - writing an array to a hash without overwriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do the following

```
my_hash = Hash.new
my_hash[:children] = Array.new
```

I then have a function that calls itself a number of time each time writing to children

```
my_hash[:children] = my_replicating_function(some_values)
```

How do I write without overwriting data that is already written ?

This is what the entire function looks like

```
def self.build_structure(candidates, reports_id)
 structure = Array.new
 candidates.each do |candidate, index|
  if candidate.reports_to == reports_id
    structure = candidate
    structure[:children] = Array.new
    structure[:children] = build_structure(candidates, candidate.candidate_id)
  end
 end
 structure
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
structure[:children] << build_structure(candidates, candidate.candidate_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

`structure[:children] << build_structure(candidates, candidate.candidate_id)`